# How to make scroll repeat with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a slide like Snapchat site but I don't know how

[This is snapchat example](https://www.snapchat.com/geofilters#carousel-container)

```
This my code :
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hrcp9rsg/

Thank you ! Please help me

Comment: You should post your actual code, not just a link to a fiddle. Also, you should clarify your question. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: My code is in fiddle my question is too clear I write code for slide but I don't know how to make like snapchat slide

Comment: How to ask a question on StackOverflow.


 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post your code and your requst correctly

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I don't know why you asking about code and it's in fiddle

Comment: I just want idea or something that help

Comment: @programerPHP, your code _must be included **directly in your question**_. Off-site resources may be used to supplement your question, but accessing them shouldn't be required to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   
   $(document).ready(function() {     
     var start_in = 0;
     setInterval(function() {
     start_in += 226;
     $(".screenshots-slide-elms ul").each(function () {
     $(this).css({
     "transition" : "-webkit-transform 500ms ease 0s",
     "transform" : "translate3d(-"+start_in+"px, 0px, 0px)",
     }); 
      
      if(start_in>1500)
      {
      start_in = 0;
      $(this).css({
     "transition" : "-webkit-transform 500ms ease 0s",
     "transform" : "translate3d(+"+start_in+"px, 0px, 0px)",
     }); 
      }
     }); 
     },2000);      
    });
```

```css
           body,html {margin:0; padding:0;}
           .screenshots-slide {position:relative;  max-width:1100px; margin:0 auto;}
        .screenshots-slide img {width:100%;}
        .screenshots-slide li {display: inline-block; width:200px; margin:0 22px 0 0; }
        .screenshots-slide-elms ul {
         opacity: 1;
            transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
           /* width: 4620px; */
            transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease 0s;
           /*margin-left: 145px;*/
        }
        .screenshots-slide-elms {position:absolute; top:60px; white-space:nowrap; max-width:100%;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
        }
    .header-phone-background {position:relative; z-index: 1; overflow:hidden; width:100%; max-width:232px; height:480px; margin:0px auto 0 auto; background:url("http://i.imgur.com/KBGCki9.png") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100% auto;}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <div class="screenshots-slide">
    <div class="header-phone-background"></div>
    <div class="screenshots-slide-elms">
    <ul>
    <li data-saf="1"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/A5KYbufCprxt0PO57ilqs2E42MKEzCLMRn_JYLQiKZUlE1w-wN_gx_8M1qvNne3cPuYNnwEv86BQbZqxgNLyLAkVcQ"/></li>
    <li data-saf="2"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/7cIJUKDkKwgKMiYB19AqnD8m75xWGGsoTc5ifcVr1UPZGUh_sGgIX9jTyY_LiXgk6p2NydTOjqln0b3DL3nxDe7chA"/></li>
    <li data-saf="3"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GndgN9b3NKFFDPjDxtpqzTPOPhtFFGpAf_pxQ0OU-gQciDeqKRM_AwOnCwvOV78bFU6BWGFPfwwoIGG72I72-0Oe-NU"/></li>
    <li data-saf="4"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_v-HbNHvVCzS0GN0kSGkYWAF8JmJ15D7fCMKgYSa3YMFBCU0ClNSw2Ksfql7w3V1DUQc_oRZf5adnYcFSEbQyBAT"/></li>
    <li data-saf="5"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Q-tFwVB3rhhoxSq45GZ_P0O6k1EMg5TEsmVvnH1xqEOZUgRr9JTqK_Q-akm3cwIPLLhKdFHxaWqE6BcZIUnSTWkzCOk"/></li>
    <li data-saf="6"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ut4BuHGec6SD3y_RLQkfOmxfll6sSHgERWjfO3dLhKXuD11czuwK1sUlKymyP7EVNYgk2n2Pl_bFcL7ZXG1J750thg"/></li>
    <li data-saf="7"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ut4BuHGec6SD3y_RLQkfOmxfll6sSHgERWjfO3dLhKXuD11czuwK1sUlKymyP7EVNYgk2n2Pl_bFcL7ZXG1J750thg"/></li>
    <li data-saf="8"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MaxAAO8dqk08VUFKiOg3xp4wzcU9BsUfCq_d0kFGW-wOFSCU_rjJkloWnhhY6wxd1e_TZ6o5NhGxbnpSD6IUnUXGrfE"/></li>
    <li data-saf="9"><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MaxAAO8dqk08VUFKiOg3xp4wzcU9BsUfCq_d0kFGW-wOFSCU_rjJkloWnhhY6wxd1e_TZ6o5NhGxbnpSD6IUnUXGrfE"/></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No this not what I want look at the snapchat slide is continue not return